# React Admin - top level store variable and selection

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want users to be able to select a variable at the top of the page that is then used in remaining sections. This is shown in the image below as the "Select Election" dropdown. I am storing that value using the "useStore" hook. I have added a SelectInput to the filters of the page, but I am not sure how to use the SelectInput to call the useStore hook and set the value.

Using an onChange or onSelect results in a compile error where react admin is trying to set the value on creation.

[image]

Here is the code

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  List,
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  DateField,
  Filter,
  TextInput,
  SelectInput,
  useStore,
  useGetList
} from "react-admin";

const SeatsFilter = (props) => {
  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <TextInput label=" Name" source="name" alwaysOn />
      <SelectInput
        label="Select Election"
        source="electionCode"
        choices={props.allElections || []}
        alwaysOn
        (onChange here?)
      />
      <TextField source="props.electionCode" />
    </Filter>
  );
};

const SeatsList = (props) => {
  const [electionCode, setElectionCode] = useStore("electionCode", "");
  const [allElections, setAllElections] = useStore("allElections", []);
  const { data } = useGetList("elections");

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllElections(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <List
      filters={
        <SeatsFilter
          allElections={allElections || []}
          electionCode={electionCode}
          setElectionCode={setElectionCode}
        />
      }
      {...props}
      sort={{ field: "name", order: "asc" }}
    >
      <Datagrid rowClick="show">
        <TextField source="name" />
        <DateField source="updatedAt" label="Last Updated" />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};

export default SeatsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this turned out to be a typo.

I should have done this ...

```
onChange={(event) => props.setElectionCode(event.target.value)}
```

I was doing this

```
onChange={props.setElectionCode(event.target.value)}
```